# Axios data coming out to be undefined

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js, axios

I have a route in nodeJs which looks like this

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.user)
 res.json(req.user)
})
```

Here console.log showing undefined but if I visit the address `(localhost:3000/)`

it displays the following the data (in json)

```
// 20181025193337
// http://localhost:3000/

{
  "isFormFilled": false,
  "_id": "5bd1a3d82101d36407f81218",
  "username": "Rohit Bhatia",
  "userId": "102775073203963169965",
  "image": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7HxFRQOCd9Q/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAU8/pgzBQd9X6pA/photo.jpg?sz=250",
  "__v": 0
}
```

Similarly from my react app, I making a axios request where response.data is coming out to be undefined (or "")

```
 componentWillMount() {
         axios.get("http://localhost:3000/").then(response => {
             console.log(response)
         }).catch(error => {
             console.log(error)
         })
    }
```

If I do something like this in my route

```
 app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.user)
     res.json("here)
    })
```

the data in my `axios` request is showing as `"Here"`

**[Question:]** Why could this be happening or what could I be doing wrong here?

**Ps:** I have enabled crocs resource sharing since I am making request locally

Comment: Making request locally does not mean that CORS is allowed.

Comment: No, I mean I have using plugin to allow cross origin request. 
The reason and the answer for the undefined data is because req.user cookie does not request when I do axios request but is present when I directly go to localhost:3000

Comment: Your question is not complete. I suggest you past whole server file code instead of just app.get. Checking the repository you gave me (https://github.com/irohitb/goodED) I see that this is a passport authentication middleware related question. Passport adds a user property to the request object. Because in your axios request you provide nothing that will allow passport to create a user (like a cookie or authentication header) it returns undefined.

Comment: @croraf I realised that posting this question and since there were already answers, I can't remove/delete this question

Comment: Can you join the chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182530/discussion-between-croraf-and-varun-bindal

Answer (score 0):

You're console.logging `req.user` which isn't in your object, hence why it's undefined. `console.log(req.userId)` or `console.log(req.username)` and notice that it is defined

Comment: userID is inside req.user