# Using NodeJs with React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

what is the correct way to use NodeJs with React?

Currently what I am doing is running `Node on port 3000` and `React on port 3001`

Now, I my Node I have this route

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.user)
 res.json(req.user)
})
```

Here `console.log` shows user details when I manually go to `localhost:3000` but If I make an axios request from my react to the above given url it shows undefined.

```
  componentWillMount() {
             axios.get("http://localhost:3000/").then(response => {
                 console.log(response)
             }).catch(error => {
                 console.log(error)
             })
        }
```

Now, The `req.user` is something which were getting from passport google Stratergy and I since the log from localhost:3000 shows the data and the log from localhost:3001 does not show data.

I am confused if I am using the node correct way? i.e sending in request via `axios` and getting data via `res.json`

Also, since most of the tutorial or the tutorial I followed used EJS instead of React where user mostly did `res.render`

I just wanted to know the **equivalence of res.render for react in NodeJS**

**[Update:]** I am enabling cross origin resource sharing via plugin in google chrome

Comment: You are making a cross origin request (CORS), port 3001 vs 3000. If you inspect console in Chrome it will show you the warning that data will be clreared before returing it to you.

Comment: @croraf I am enabling cross origin resource sharing via plugin in google chrome

Comment: You are using it correctly. In fact this has nothing to do with React. You are just missing something regarding CORS. I had the same issue lately, when the data returned in browser was set to undefined, while node was sending the correct data. Are you using koa in node?

Comment: Do you use create-react-app ?

Comment: @croraf Nope. Googling koa

Comment: @AsafAviv Yap. using create-react-app

Comment: Does "console.log(response)" in componentWillMount run at all?

Comment: @croraf Yap (with data being empty).
You can fork my repo and try it out here 
https://github.com/irohitb/goodED

Comment: @croraf also try my previous question for some additional details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52991355/axios-data-coming-out-to-be-undefined/52992139#52992139

Comment: I've added link for express server (that I see you are using) cors solution in my answer.

Comment: @croraf looks interesting, let me try it out. Thanks :)

Comment: But I see your other question that the issue is with req.user, and if you return the simple string instead of req.user it works fine. If this is true than it is not CORS issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182530/discussion-between-croraf-and-varun-bindal).

Comment: A simple is string is returned when I enable cross origin request. If i turn it off, it won't return that string as well

Answer (score 3):

### EDIT: In discussion with OP I found out that this is most likely a passport authentication middleware related issue. Original answer follows.

---

Looks like a CORS issue, as your frontend providing server is on port 3001, and backend on 3000. I can show you the way I'm using it (in react+node CORS setup, although the issue has nothing to do with React) and I have no CORS issues:

On frontend I use native browser's fetch:

```
const fetchRelative = async (path, options) => {

    const url = new URL('http://localhost:3000/' + path);

    return await ((await fetch(url, options)).json());
};
```

Here async/await syntax is used. I'm using babel for transpile, but maybe browsers support that natively.

Options provided to fetch are for example:

```
{
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(order),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
};
```

For a simple get request you can leave the options parameter empty.

---

On backend (node+koa server) I use this:

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const koaBody = require('koa-body');
const cors = require('koa-cors');

const startServer = (port) => {

    const server = new Koa();

    server.use(cors({ origin: '*', allowMethods: ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT', 'OPTIONS'] }));

    server.use(koaBody());    
    
    server.use(bindRoutes());
    
    server.listen(port);
};
```

Basically the same is for express server (https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html).

bindRoutes is just koa-router configuration extracted in a separate file:

```
const Router = require('koa-router');
const bindRoutes = () => {
    const router = new Router();

    router.get('restaurants', async (ctx) => {
        ctx.body = 'abc;
    });

    return router.routes();
};
```

CORS plugin is not used here.

P.S.

> async/await explaination and Browser support status
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function
>
> fetch explaination and Browser support status
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, I am reading about koa 

Also, Instead of Fetch I am using axios and since axios returns promise, I think I might not need async?

Answer (score 0):

You can run both your Node server and React app on different ports and proxy the React app back to your Node server. This can be done without a CORS plugin. More details on how to set this up is here: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0

Comment: Daveskull thanks for answering, read that article and tried but my *"proxy": "http://localhost:3000/"* doesn't seem to be working. 

It sends a request to localhost:3001 instead of "http://localhost:3000/" 

You can fork and try my git repo: https://github.com/irohitb/goodED