# React Node Unable to pass cookie to the browser (crocs error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, passport.js

For some reason I am unable to store cookie in my browser.

This is the first time I am working with **React And NodeJS**

My React application is working on `localhost:3000` and NodeJS application on `localhost:8080`

The Git repository for the [same happens to be this](https://github.com/irohitb/goodED)

So, I am successfully able to login, store the credentials in DB and probably serialise and de-serialise.

I am not sharing the code for Google Strategy and serialise and de-serialise since I believe that problem doesn't presist here (In case you think that you would need to view it [click here](https://github.com/irohitb/goodED/blob/master/server/config/passport-config.js)

This Google redirect [returns at following callback](https://github.com/irohitb/goodED/blob/master/server/routes/auth.js)

```
   router.get("/google/callback", passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: "/", session: false }), (req, res) => {


      res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/")
  })
```

In my [**server.js**](https://github.com/irohitb/goodED/blob/master/server/server.js) (main file, I start node server by doing node server.js), I am doing this to store cookie

```
app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: ['http://localhost:3000'] // here goes any Frontend IP Adress
}))

//We are setting cookie here 
app.use(cookieSession({
  maxAge: 24*60*60*1000, //cookies is valid for a day
  keys: ['fgfhfjhfad'] 
}))  


app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
```

And then when I do this in [my react frontend](https://github.com/irohitb/goodED/blob/master/src/container/authentication/signup/signupMain.js)

```
 componentWillMount() {
         axios.get("http://localhost:8080/",  {withCredentials: true}).then(response => {
             console.log(response)
         }).catch(error => {
             console.log(error)
         })
    }
```

Where my [localhost:3000/](https://github.com/irohitb/goodED/blob/master/server/server.js) looks like this

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    if (req.isFormFilled) {
      res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/home")
    } else {
      res.json(req.user)
    }
  } else {
  res.json("user does not exsist")
  }
})
```

It always log `res.json("user does not exsist")` but if I directly go to localhost:3000 in my browser, I can see my req.user < **[See: update below question]**

Ps; I am enabling cross-origin request in my browser

**[Question:]** Can someone please help me in finding out what I could be doing wrong?

**[Update:]** It appears we might be having crocs error, I have changed my code and I am getting this as an error in frontend

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8080' from origin
>   'localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the
>   wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The
>   credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute

If I remove  `{withCredentials: true}` in my **axios** request the above error disappears but then it logs **user does not exsist** in **response.data**

Comment: While the other answers may be technically correct, a more fundamental question is why your frontend and backend are running on different ports.. The CORS error you're running into is the browser trying to prevent a website from calling to an unknown, possibly malicious outside entity. You'll generally want both services running on the same port to emulate them originating from the same domain.

Comment: @RyanVillanueva Please share your answer here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996320/using-nodejs-with-react

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So send Cookies via REST its neccecary to:

Set Cors serverside:

```
app.use(cors({
    'allowedHeaders': ['sessionId', 'Content-Type'],
    'exposedHeaders': ['sessionId'],
    'credentials': true,
    'origin': ['http://[FRONTEND-IP]:[FRONTEND-PORT]', 'http://[ALTERNATIVE-FRONTEND-IP]:[FRONTEND-PORT]'],
}))
```

For Frontend you need to setup a call like this:

```
fetch('http://[API-IP]:[API-PORT]/call', {credentials: 'include'}).then((result) => {
    return result.json()
}).then((data) => {
    //Do something
});
```

you can also use fetch asynchronous:

```js
async function loadData() {
    let response = await fetch(
        'http://[API-IP]:[APi-PORT]/call', 
        {credentials: 'include'}
    );
    return response.json();
}
```

this, of course, applies to using a rest service with json bodies.
If you rely on another structure than json, you need to parse your response manually.

Also, An interested article on web about cors https://50linesofco.de/post/2017-03-06-cors-a-guided-tour

Comment: You are a champ, This works. Just change the origin address to `3000` instead of `8080` . Also, Just to let you know, Someone else downvoted your answer and I upvoted it :) 
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @anny123  It doesn't work for me, is it because they have a different port?

Comment: @jcarlosweb Sandro is the actual author of the answer. You should tag and ask him

Comment: You need to add all of your ip addresses you use for your frontend in order to allow the cors requests as desired. But as of your backend runs on another port than your frontend does. So you need another port in your fetch request

Comment: this made my day. Thanks, @Sandro Schaurer.

Answer (score 2):

If you face Problems with Passport-Sessions try to use 'express-session' instead.

'express-session' Creates Cookies itself and sends it.

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}))
```

If you use this you can grab the session in each rest call.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    req.session.[anyVariableUWantHere] = true;
    res.send('done');
});
```

Now the session is created.

If you get any Problems with React try this:

in server.js:
    app.use(cors({
        credentials: true,
        [...]
    }))

now you just need to edit your 'fetch' in React like that:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/call', {credentials: 'include'}).then((result) => {
    return result.json()
}).then((data) => {
    //Do something
});
```

The credentials: 'include' is important for React to get the Session-Cookie.
By Default fetch is not loading any Cookies.

Comment: to use express-session, would i need to change `app.use(passport.initialize())` as well?

Comment: I dont know much about passport ... but may you need to change something here.
Try to make sure that there are no other sessions than the express-session one

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering but i am using passport strategy and hence i would probably prefer using passport session.

Comment: so may you can try if the fetch with credentials: include helps .... may its enough to get it to work :)

Comment: do you have cors on serverside enabled ?

Comment: Yap, `app.use(cors())`

Comment: is 'credentials' set to true ?

Comment: I am not sure what does that mean or how we do it?

Comment: app.use(cors({ credentials: true }))

Comment: Did that. Nope, Problem still remains

Comment: Can you try forking and moving around to see it by yourself. 
Probably it will make more sense then?

Comment: `{credentials: 'include'}` in axios (or fetch request) throws **cors** error

Comment: what is the error about ? may you need to set cors to an specific origin

Comment: If I do something like this   `axios.get("http://localhost:8080/",  {withCredentials: true}).then(response => {
             console.log(response)` then I get following error **Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute** I have enabled cors on my server(1/2)

Comment: And in the client side I am using a plugin to enable cross origin request

Comment: ok so go for the serverside cors:

`app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: ['http://localhost:3001', 'http://yourIP:3001']}))`

Comment: yap. i am doing that. I have also changed my server side address to `localhost:8080` and client side to `localhost:3000` . This is how my cors is looking 
`
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true,

}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));` **note:** pushing the commit on my github repo to reflect the same

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182530/discussion-between-croraf-and-varun-bindal

Comment: Look my last Post => I updated it.

There you see that the options of cors needs to be inside ' '